# How node server can automatically redirect same as browser

Tags: node.js

I am configuring a service provider client for authenticate via a third party Id provider. The thing is that it all work fine on the browser, however, I like to make the same process using the API. When I web browse my service provider login endpoint  url, it redirect me to the identity provider login page where I put my username and password and i am redirected to my service provider with a authentication token. The problem when trying to do this via API is that when I make a node request service provider login endpoint  url, the response.end take me into a intermediate url which according the header nee to be redirected. So my answer is: how can I get the login URL as final node response? Here is the header of the intermediate page

```
:authority: dev-xssqpfdr.auth0.com
:method: POST
:path: /samlp/z76124e23wGhWOCp0HLCa3pR2Bs5BmYyj
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 5389
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cookie: auth0=s%3AfyaKW_M79aXfsB_RXakNH7zrwZGr-J04.icMGIxicIaBxhWfscSvmd4aSK33piQWDkaenfv2wgWO4
origin: https://devbank-invistacompi.cs79.force.com
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://devbank-cs79.force.com/
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your API to be directly accessible. It's no use to have a manual redirection in between and you'd ass another level of complexity into the logic.

The thing is that the client needs to sort this issue out. So in your case, you have something like an initialize step that queries the URL. With the response you can configure your application to use the proper endpoint.

Again: this is poor design. If possible, you should put some load balancer or HA proxy between your known endpoint and your server. That way you can scale and do inspection on the requests.